# AutofacContrib.Multitenant is not available in NuGet

Tags: autofac

I am using [`Autofac` 2.6.1.841](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/2.6.1.841) in my project. For some functionality i have to use `AutofacContrib.Multitenant.dll` (2.6.1.841) and it is not available in `NuGet`.

So how can i get this dll from `NuGet`. Is there any replacement for `AutofacContrib.Multitenant.dll` ?

Comment: There is a nuget package for Autofac 3 http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.Multitenant/ But if you want to use an older version. You need to use the old way: download the dll from the project homepage and add a reference for it manually.

Comment: @nemesv, I didn't find AutofacContrib.Multitenant.dll (2.6.1.841) from NuGet or https://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list

Comment: It is a Deprecated download: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=AutofacContrib-2.6.1.841-NET40.zip&can=4&q=

Comment: @nemesv, Thanks for response. I got the dll from Deprecated downloads with url you have provided. But, What is the procedure to ask the NuGet team to include this dll as part of NuGet Gallery . Because all dll's we are using in project is available in NuGet except this.

Comment: The nuget team **does not** mantain the packages, but the individaul project owners. So you should ask the Autofac team to create a legacy package or you can create and upload your own package: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutofacContrib.Multitenant was never released on NuGet. The first NuGet version was after switching to Autofac 3.0, when we updated all the NuGet packages and assemblies to be Autofac.Extras.* instead of AutofacContrib.*. At that time, we also started releasing all of the Extras packages on NuGet.

There is no plan to retroactively add packages for deprecated versions, so if you can't upgrade to Autofac 3.0 and switch over to the Autofac.Extras.* versions of things, the best we can offer is to go to [the downloads section on Google Code and get it there](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list?can=4&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).